# Как управлять расположением блоков при адаптивной верстке ?

Tags: адаптивная-верстка, html, css

Есть 3 блока, они все стоят в ряд. При ресайзе на определенное разрешение нужно взять центровой блок и поместить вперед, остальные два под него, вот таким образом.

[image]

Возможно ли такое реализовать без flexbox?

Comment: Создай отдельную таблицу стилей для мобильных устройств и попробуй поэксперементировать в ней.

Answer (score 1):

Проблему решили бутстрап сетки:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-4  col-sm-push-4">
        <div class="content red">1</div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-4">
        <div class="content">2</div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6  col-sm-4">
        <div class="content">3</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Очень грязно, но http://jsfiddle.net/x0sfmw38/1/